# How to override the "MuiPaper-elevation1" atrribute in a Card component in Material-UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Card component which is as below in HTML:
`<div class="MuiPaper-root MuiCard-root makeStyles-Card-5 MuiPaper-elevation1 MuiPaper-rounded">`

And I need to change the `MuiPaper-elevation1` to `MuiPaper-elevation0`, which remove the shadow.

I tried

```
    <Card
      MuiPaperElevation0
      MuiPaper-elevation0
      style={{ boxShadow: 0 }}
    >
```

but it doesn't work, nothing changed and the shadow is still there.

Could someone teach me how to do it plz?
Thx!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the underlying Paper props like this:

```
<Card
  elevation={0}
>
```

Essentially you can apply any prop to card that you would apply to the Paper element

Answer (score 3):

The Card API accepts an elevation prop (inherited from the Paper component). In order to change the elevation, you pass it a number. This will remove the box shadow without needing to add your own styling
API: https://material-ui.com/api/paper/

```
<Card elevation={0}>
....
</Card>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should just set boxShadow to none:

```
<Card style={{ boxShadow: 'none' }} >
```

Comment: If you're using makeStyles you can do something like this as well!

const useStyles = makeStyles({
CardStyling: {
   boxShadow: 'none',
  },
});